# Expected number of bins with more than one ball

Tags: probability, expectation, balls-in-bins

Suppose that $n$ balls are randomly thrown into $N$ bins.  We can compute the expected number of bins that contain at least one ball as $E(X) = N(1 - (1 - 1/N)^n)$.

Now, suppose that instead we are asked for the expected number $E(Y)$ of bins that contain more than one ball.  Can we recover this from $n$ and $E(X)$?  My intuition is suggesting that this ought to be $E(Y) = n - E(X)$, but I'm not sure one way or the other.

My intuition is coming from the pigeon hole principle, I think.  If $E(X)$ bins are occupied, and there are $n$ balls, then $n - E(X)$ balls are in a bin with at least one more ball in it.  Granted, that doesn't tell me how the $n - E(X)$ balls are distributed in the  bins.

I am trying to compute the expected number of bins with exactly one ball directly.  Let $N_i$ be the number of balls in the $i$th bin, and let $Z_i = 1$ if $N_i = 1$, and $Z_i = 0$ otherwise.

Each $N_i$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $p = 1/N$.  Then $E(Z_i) = P(Z_i = 1) = P(N_i = 1) = \frac{n}{N} \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^{n-1}$.  So $E(Z) = n\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^{n-1}$.

Comment: To be clear, $E(X)$ is the expected number of bins that contain *exactly* one ball, or is $E(X)$ the expected number of bins that contain *at least* one ball?

Comment: At least one.  Edited.

Comment: Wrong solution accepted the minute it is posted. Then duly upvoted. Well, who am I to object?

Comment: @Did: please do!  I'm still trying to figure out how it's binomial.

Comment: Sorry but I see no binomial distribution in the formula of the posted answer.

Comment: @Did: sorry to disturb you again, but does the write up in my question look sensible?

Comment: The expression for E(Z) at the end of your post is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The expected number of bins with at least one ball is

$$ E(\geq 1) = N(1-(1-1/N)^n) $$

and the expected number with precisely one ball is (from the binomial distribution)

$$ E(1)=N(1-1/N)^{n-1} $$

so

$$ E(>1)=E(\geq 1)-E(1) = N(1-(1-1/N)^{n-1}(2-1/N)) $$

which doesn't seem to equal $n-E(\geq 1)$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the '1' case is binomial.

Comment: Your expression goes to $- N$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$, while surely it should go to zero?

Comment: @Rudyard That's not how limits work. There is an N factor outside. You cannot just plug the limit in the later term and ignore the outer $N$.

Comment: Shouldn't `E(1)` be `n * (1 - 1/N)^(n-1)`? This is because the binomial term in the PMF gives `n` while the `N` from summing over the bins is cancelled out.